# Opening new tab based on Javascript output (broken code)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I’m making a hosting site, and I am trying to have a form where you can search a domain from a form. Check out the pseudocode to understand what I’m trying to do.

User types domain/search in box -> Presses DONE -> Opens new tab with the below format (with the user’s query)

https://example.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=QUERY_HERE

Here’s my code, but when the form submission, it searches domain=example.com (if I put example.com in the search box). What did I do wrong?

JavaScript (with JQuery):

```
$('.done').on('click', function() {

    var dataArray = $('#message').serializeArray();
  
    window.open('https://billing.zapprhosting.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=' + $.param( dataArray ));
  
  });
```

HTML Form:

```
<form id="message" target="_blank">
    <input id="domain-text" type="text" name="domain" placeholder="Write your domain name here.." />
</form>
<div class="button-center done">
     <a href="#"><p>SUBMIT</p></a>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION:**
This took some more reworking of how I tackled the problem, but this is the final code which works.

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn").click( function() {
    var url = "https://billing.zapprhosting.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=" + $("#text").val();
    window.open(url);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

Pretty simple page, but useful for scaling up to larger projects. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Comment: `serializeArray` gets you an array of the form `[{name: "domain", value: "foobar"}]`, and `$.param` makes `domain=foobar` out of that - _as it should_. You are simply using methods here, that make rather little sense for what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: This wouldn't need any JavaScript at all, if you made the form action point to `https://billing.zapprhosting.com/cart.php` directly, named your input field `query`, and added hidden fields for the static parameters. Combine with an _actual_ submit button, instead of an `a` that gets _abused_ as one, and ... done.

Answer (score 0):

This took some more reworking of how I tackled the problem, but this is the final code which works.

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn").click( function() {
    var url = "https://billing.zapprhosting.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=" + $("#text").val();
    window.open(url);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```

Pretty simple page, but useful for scaling up to larger projects. Thanks for the help everyone :)